# Strange path when compiling python in VsCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, path

everyone. I've been using python for a while with PyCharm, however I decided to go back on VsCode because I'm used to it.

I installed the python extension, specified the interpreter and compiled a basic file. Everything seems ok, except a strange path in the terminal which is annoying.

When I compile JavaScript it specifies the path rather simple: 
`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe tests.js`

However when I compile python it is a lot bigger:

```
PS D:\Projects\>  ${env:DEBUGPY_LAUNCHER_PORT}='12345'; & 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python
\Python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\Users\user1\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\pythonFiles
\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher' 'd:\Projects\app.py'
```

My question is, is this normal and is there a way to remove it or should I get comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. One, that's not compiling your code, it's running your code under the the debugger. Python doesn't really have a compiler step in the traditional sense.

Two, there isn't anything you can do about it. It's how the debugger launches.

Comment: Yes, but it's basically an implementation detail. For instance, `.pyc` files are just a performance optimization and you can have Python not read or write them.